Verify the design flow from Service layer to Repository to Mapper class
I have a Service class , injects the RepoService.
In RepoServiceImpl class, injects the Mapper.
In Mapper class, injects the RepoService,as I have to use repoService again to the get the records.
Reposervice is an interface and is implemented in RepoServiceImpl.
    class Service {
    
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("repoService")
        private RepoService repoService;
    
        public void create() {
            repoService.createRecord();
        }
    
    }
    
    @Service
    @Qualifier("repoService")
    class RepoServiceImpl implements RepoService {
    
    @Autowired
    private mapper;
    
     createRecord(){
      mapper.createMapper();
    }

   getRecord(){
          
     }
  }

    
    @Component
    class Mapper {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("repoService")
        private RepoService repoService;

      createMapper(){
        repoService.getRecord();
      }
    }

Need to check the design flow, do I need to change in the design?

Each layer has specific meaning.
Controller - Manage rest interface to business logic
Service - business logic implementation
Repository - connection with database and storage/retrieval  of entity to/from database.
So as per your design-
Repository layer should contains only database related operation only.
Service layer should contains both repo service and mapper.
Conversion of database entity to DTO is part of your business logic.

I think there is a circular reference between Mapper class and RepoService.
How about adding Repository and configuring it like this?
Service -> Mapper -> Repository
@Service
class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    private final Mapper mapper;
}

@Component
class Mapper {
    private final Repository repository;
}

@Repository
class RepositoryImpl implements Repository {
    private final Mapper mapper;
}


